# How to list all files , ignoring subdirectories, in a Google Drive's root location using Google's REST v3 API?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I've followed the example [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android) and managed to get it to work listing a bunch of files from my Google Drive account, however the files it returns aren't from the root location and simply seem to be what was last updated. I've wrapped the `activityLayout` in a `ScrollView` and increased the `setPageSize(10)` to 100 but other than that my code remains the same to the example. How can have `getDataFromApi()` return a full list of every file within the root directory while ignoring subdirectories? Also, I'd like to do the same but for folders instead of files too as an extra.

Answer (score 0):

[Files.list](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.Files.List.html) returns all the files from you Google Drive, no other method will. It might be that you have 100+ files and it happened that what was initially returned was what you weren't looking for. In that case use the nextPageToken to access the second batch of files 101-200.

If you want a more filtered search use [search queries](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters).

Comment: What I want is the files in the root of the drive account, `files().list()` returns a list of files that not only include files from the root but from within subfolders too which isn't what I want.

Comment: Use search query filter  parents = 'root'